# SQL - Obtener ocurrencias anteriores en columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando dar con una consulta de "ordenes de compra" en la que quiero mostrar el valor de la penúltima y antepenúltima ocurrencia cronológicamente.
No tengo la más mínima idea sobre como "pivotear" las ocurrencias anteriores, alguna ayuda porfavor.
El código:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Producto ORDER BY t1.Fecha DESC), a.NumeroDocumento, a.Fecha, b.Producto, b.Cantidad, b.Precio
FROM Encabezados AS t1
LEFT JOIN Detalle AS t2 ON t1.NumeroDocumento = t2.NumeroDocumento
```

Quiero obtener el siguiente resultado:

| Row_Number | NumeroDocumento | Fecha | Producto | Cantidad | Precio | Precio(RowNum+1) | Fecha(RowNum+1) | Precio(RowNum+2) | Fecha(RowNum+2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 999 | 01-05-2020 | Producto1 | 100 | 2 | 1.98 | 20-04-2020 | 1.85 | 02-02-2020 |
| 2 | 980 | 20-04-2020 | Producto1 | 100 | 1.98 | 1.85 | 02-02-2020 | 0 | 0 |

Edit: Estoy usando SQL Server

Comment: Edita las etiquetas y agrega qué motor de base de datos estás utilizando.

Comment: Estas bien encaminado. Luego de enumerar por fecha DESC para cada producto,  en otra query filtra las filas con munero de fila 2 y 3.

Comment: @nachospiu mi intención es dejar que el ROW_NUMBER de la consulta principal de siempre la tendencia para las 2 anteriores, es decir, cuando en la consulta principal sea Row_Number = 199, entonces muestra la 200 y 201 si es que existen.

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendí bien tu requerimiento, sino me corriges. Si lo que quieres es obtener la información de la penúltima y antepenúltima orden de compra para cada producto, como te decía en los comentarios, primero tienes que enumerar las filas por producto ordenando por fecha (de la orden de compra) descendente (esto lo habías hecho bien en tu query). La última compra para cada producto quedará con orden 1, la penultima con orden 2 y la antepenultima con orden 3; por lo tanto lo que resta es filtrar solo aquellas filas con orden 2 y 3.

Ten en cuenta que si un producto nunca fue comprado o solo fue comprado una vez no va a aparecer en el resultado.

Para escribir la query me base en la query que escribistes vos (ya que no cuento con el modelo de datos). Asumo que NumeroDocumento es el identificador de la orden de compra, y por ello lo utilizas para vincular.

```
WITH listado AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Producto ORDER BY e.Fecha DESC) AS orden, 
                        e.NumeroDocumento, e.Fecha, d.Producto, d.Cantidad, d.Precio
                 FROM Encabezados AS e
                 INNER JOIN Detalle AS d ON e.NumeroDocumento = d.NumeroDocumento)
                 
SELECT *
FROM listado
WHERE orden IN (2, 3);
```

Edité la query anterior para obtener para cada fila el precio y la fecha de la fila siguiente y la subsiguiente (utilizando la función `LEAD()`:

```
WITH listado AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Producto ORDER BY e.Fecha DESC) AS orden, 
                        e.NumeroDocumento, e.Fecha, d.Producto, d.Cantidad, d.Precio,
                        LEAD(d.Precio) OVER (PARTITION BY d.Producto ORDER BY e.Fecha DESC) AS precio_f1,
                        LEAD(e.Fecha) OVER (PARTITION BY d.Producto ORDER BY e.Fecha DESC) AS fecha_f1,
                        LEAD(d.Precio, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY d.Producto ORDER BY e.Fecha DESC) AS precio_f2,
                        LEAD(e.Fecha, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY d.Producto ORDER BY e.Fecha DESC) AS fecha_f2
                 FROM Encabezados AS e
                 INNER JOIN Detalle AS d ON e.NumeroDocumento = d.NumeroDocumento)
                 
SELECT *
FROM listado
WHERE orden IN (2, 3);
```

Comment: Lo que falta es que necesito listar las ordenes de compra, considerando encabezados + detalle y hasta ahí entiendo tu query. Luego a ese mismo query, necesito por cada cambio en Producto, mostrar el precio unitario de la orden Row_Number +1 y +2.
Así cuando tenga una orden RowNumber = 10, mostrar la todo el detalle de la 10, precio unitario de la '11' y de la '12' respectivamente.

Comment: Bien, ahí agregué una segunda query en la que para cada fila trae el precio y la fecha de la siguiente fila y la subsiguiente del mismo producto, si existriera dicha información (para cada producto las filas las ordena por fecha descediente). Probalo y cualquier cosa me avisas.